# Python3: Permissions of file at receiver send over HTTP

Tags: python, file

On Ubuntu 16.10, using Python3, I'm sending a file over HTTP to a destination (which may or may not be the same device) like so:

```
# send to node
files = {'filearg': (filename, open('cerberos_mgmt/services/service.java', 'rb+'))}
resource = requests.post('http://' + service_url + '/pool/resources/' + parameters['uid'], files=files)
```

This file, at the sender, is owned by the user and has full Read, Write and Execute permissions.

At the receiver however, it becomes owned by root and has read-only access.
The receiver implements the following post method:

```
async def post(self, id):
    """
    Used to send a service to a node OTA
    :return:
    """

    # redirect user to main page
    self.redirect('/pool')

    # write to file
    path = "files/"
    fileinfo = self.request.files['filearg'][0]

    fname = fileinfo['filename']
    extn = os.path.splitext(fname)[1]
    #cname = str(uuid.uuid4()) + extn

    cname = fname
    fh = open(path + cname, 'w')

    # find address and SRV_ID
    address = None
    srv_id = None
    *snip*

    file_str = str(fileinfo['body'],'utf-8')
    file_str = sub(r'public static int SRV_ID = [0-9]*;', 'public static int SRV_ID = ' + str(srv_id) + ';', file_str)

    fh.write(file_str)
    fh.close()

    # deploy
    chunk['status'] = 'Deploying'
    state = await self.pool_object.iot_api.deploy_service(file_path=os.path.abspath(path + cname), address=address)
    chunk['status'] = state
```

Specifically, I'm sending a .java file. When trying to compile this java file at the receiver, I get this error:

```
CLASSPATH=./BUILDENV/RT//real:./BUILDENV/RT//fake:./BUILDENV/RT//fake/uj ./../files//Test_Wait20.java
/bin/sh: 1: ./../files//Test_Wait20.java: Permission denied
Makefile:18: recipe for target 'compile_service' failed
make: *** [compile_service] Error 126
```

So permission issues and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or where the permissions are changed.

Comment: What operating system is this script running on? Need to know to provide information on how to change permissions in a command line. Thanks.

Comment: Apologies, Ubuntu 16.10. Added to main post.

Comment: When receiver perform `ls -al` in that folder structure, does the new write permission is updated?

Comment: You might want to just not run your service as root and set up a sensible umask. This is saner than having your service shell out to run chmod.

Comment: @ Gaurav: it gives this: " -rw-r--r--  1 root root  960 Mar  8 09:33 Test_Wait20.java "

@pvg: problem is, I'm working with many different devices (Raspberry Pi's, Linux VMs, ... ) and also need stuff like /dev/tty access. So root is handy to do. Unless I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: your python web service that receives files over the network probably doesn't need to run as root, though, does it? Either way, if the file has world read permissions your compile is not failing because of permissions of the file you wrote.

Comment: Apologies, deleted my answer since it was not helpful. I cannot provide any more solutions unfortunately.

Comment: @pvg, you are right. No permission issue, but rather something I forgot to include for compiling. Thank you!

Comment: Out of curiosity what are you using to handle the inbound http requests? Are you sanitizing the input in some way? filename in particular. Cause if you aren't, this also turns into a service for trashing any file on your filesystem

Comment: This is for an internal in-house test service, so no due diligence being done, I'm afraid ;-)

@Harvey, no problem

Comment: Internal or not, you can literally typo your way to doing something awful. I'm not talking about hiring a firm to do a security audit, just apply standard practices. But anyway, it's your thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP only transports the data of the file - and your code is explicit on that point. So the owner and permissions are set by the receiver. IMHO the simplest way (assuming a Unix like system, but you have already speaked of *root*) is to set the umask to 0 while creating the file, and reset it when done:

```
...
cname = fname
old_umask = os.umask(0)                 # give all permissions to created files
try:
    fh = open(path + cname, 'w')
    ...
    fh.close()
finally:
    dummy = os.umask(old_umask)             # restore the original umask
```